# Which character encoding to use

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

If I go through my Twitter feed I can see tweets which are of different languages (Some are English, some are Chinese, some have European characters, some even have emojis). I would also like to support multiple languages and emojis inside of my app. If I have a MySQL database for example and have a column called 'message_content' which stores messagess content, how can I ensure the data under this column can support all languages+emojis?

I am not sure if it is as simple as choosing a character encoding and that's it or if it is more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

[utf8mb4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) is a good choice for this.

Comment: And be sure to set it in the connection, the table, and html.